# Case-less Power Triac Part Number Identification

Tags: identification, triac, lighting

I am trying to identify the part number of this high current (20A) triac. It was originally covered in potting, and it appears to have four pins (2 power, 2 control). It would appear to be something like this [BCR30GM](https://pim.galco.com/Manufacturer/Powerex/TechDocument/Data%20Sheet/bcr30gm-12_dat.pdf) except that it does not have a case. The power triac circuit appears to follow [Fig. 23 of this App Note](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84780/appnote34.pdf)

[image: Image of mystery part]

The PCB is ceramic and is bonded to a heatsink, to dissipate the heat. The part is driven by a [IL420](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83629/il420.pdf) optocoupler, triac driver. The [entire module](https://www.fullcompass.com/prod/093463-etc-q141-power-cube-for-d20) is used to control lighting. However, I have a number of them with failed triacs and would like to replace the part (or design a replacement PCB) since purchasing new modules is quite pricey.

Did they get the component manufacturer to produce these 'case-less' power triacs special for them or is there a place they can be purchased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual TRIAC looks to be a wafer here, apparently soldered underneath the copper prongs. Might be able to separate it with hot air, but the chip itself is unlikely to be a commercially-available part. The manufacturer likely orders them custom in ten-thousand quantity or more.

If these are failing prematurely, are they being overdriven, connected to inappropriate lamp type, or allowed to exceed temperature?  Is there a cooling fan, and is it working?

If internal TRIAC replacement were attempted with a discrete (off-the-shelf, available) device in say a TO-3P or TO-247 package, how would you anchor the (now removed) prong?  Also consider soldering the tab to the existing heat sink location. Low-temp solder may be needed, simply because it is going to be a challenge to get enough heat into it without cooking the TRIAC.  And is that tab electrically isolated? The ceramic "board" may or may not electrically insulate it - hard to tell from the photo.  If it does not, then my gut feeling is that the thermal conductivity (from chip, through ceramic, to heatsink) is not very good and the chip is getting too hot and failing. It really doesn't help that it is soldered and sandwiched between ceramic and copper - materials with different thermal expansion coefficients. And insertion and removal force is exerted directly on the chip (don't drop a module or slam it - it could readily stress-fracture the wafer.)

All-in-all, this seems like a lot of work for a very finnicky and no-guarantee repair.  Might be easier to remove the whole module and permanently wire in a more robust solution (such as 30A TRIACs.)  That would still need heatsink(s) and cooling though - quite a "retrofit" challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to identify it, just get the cheapest triac which meets all the requirements you know of and which is the easiest to fit or integrate with the module. They are generic components whose exact model is unimportant most of the time, as long as they serve your purpose.